# swagger unique operationId means odd-looking code from swagger-js

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

Having read up on the specs, I see that each operationId must be unique across the entire spec. I know this is the requirement, but it still seems odd that it's not unique within the path / route.

So, as a result of this uniqueness, if I have a route of `SomeLongModelName` and a method of `someMethod` the operationID becomes `SomeLongModelName.SomeMethod` and the code generated by swagger-js is therefore

`SomeLongModelName.SomeLongModelName_SomeMethod().then`

which just looks ... horrible ...

Is there anyway of getting swagger-js to generate client methods like

`SomeLongModelName.SomeMethod` instead ?

Comment: You may consider using Swagger Codegen to generate JS API client instead of using swagger-js (dynamic API client)

Comment: you mean by modifying the mustache template to remove the `model_` bit at the front ? Yeah - I'll have a look at that. The problem is that then creates the need to write out source code instead of just using a library. 

Thanks for the top though. It's worth looking at